# How to get Hadoop client to user correct credentials in a secure (Kerberos) clusters

Tags: java, hadoop, active-directory, kerberos

I have a Hadoop (CDH412) cluster setup that has been enabled to authenticate and authorize with Kerberos.  I got everything to work fine (Hdfs, mapred, zookeeper, hbase, hive, etc).  I am, however, having an issue with accessing hdfs data from within a java app.

My Java app is a service that runs in the background.  Due to this, no password can be entered, I have to use a keytab file.  Should not be a problem.  It works fine if I do a 'kinit' first, ala...

```
kinit -kt /home/fred/kerberostest/krb5.keytab myprinc/myserver.com@MY.REALM
```

However, if I try to do this in java code (I have read that LoginContext.logon will do the same thing as the kinit), it fails.

To try to test this, I have written the following code snippet....

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "MY.REALM");
System.setProperty("java.security.kdc", "kdc.server.com");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/home/fred/kerberostest/jaas.conf");

LoginContext context = new LoginContext("Client");
context.login();

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

InputStream in = fs.open(new Path("/mytestfile"));
int b = in.read();
in.close();
```

My jaas.conf file looks like this.....

```
Client {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   debug=true
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="/home/fred/kerberostest/krb5.keytab"
   principal="myprinc/myserver.com@MY.REALM"
   useTicketCache=false;
}
```

When I run the java code, above, the LoginContext.login appears to work correctly.... I get a debug statement that says

```
Login successful for user myprinc/myserver.com@MY.REALM using keytab file /home/fred/kerberostest/krb5.keytab
```

When the code tries to open the HDFS file (fs.open), however, the app fails with an PriviledgedActionException, stating:

```
ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as :fred (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
```

So, it is trying to use "fred" (my linux logon) to access these files, instead of my principal information from the keytab file.  Again, if I do a kinit first, it works fine.... but isn't LoginContext supposed to do the same thing?

Note: This is an ActiveDirectory "version" of Kerberos.  It is not using trusts... just directly to ActiveDirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to blame this on our Active Directory implementation.  I did this with a MIT Kerberos and it worked fine.  Closed.

Comment: Shouldn't the property name be java.security.krb5.kdc as opposed to java.security.kdc

Otherwise you get:

Caused by: KrbException: System property java.security.krb5.kdc and java.security.krb5.realm both must be set or neither must be set.

Comment: My testing shows there should also be an semi colon ';' as the last character in the jaas.conf file.

Comment: Which Kerberos implementation were you having problems with?

Comment: Just for clarification, everything I had setup was correct.  The guys on the active directory did not have principals setup correctly.  When I created my own MIT Kerberos, it all worked correctly, which helped the AD guys figure out what they needed to do.